# Deploying multiple platform server on the same ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, deployment, amazon-ec2

I would like to deploy python Flask server on an already deployed RAILS app (with nginx and unicorn) instance that is running on a ubuntu with port 80 for http service.

For the saving cost reason, I would like to run an internal python server on the same ubuntu machine at different port say 8888 and let the rails app call the api that python server expose.

I did this experiment on my local development machine and it worked fine. That is, I have my rails server run at localhost:3000 and python server run at localhost:8888. The rails server can call python api with no issue. However in production environment, I am struggling to make it work. The problem is when do HTTP POST to "localhost:8888" there is HTTP error status. It does not work. I did open up port 8888 with IPTable in the ubuntu machine.

I am wondering whether this is possible in production to deploy so. Any suggestion how should I set up the python server on production so that it can be access by rails server?

update:

```
deploy@app1:~$ netstat --listen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:8888                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 ip6-localhost:2812      *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:54535                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 ip6-localhost:6379      *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:43095              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 *:38271                 *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:741                   *:*                                
udp        0      0 ip6-localhost:968       *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                                
udp        0      0 app1:ntp                *:*                                
udp        0      0 ip6-localhost:ntp       *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*                                
udp6       0      0 [::]:741                [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:40022              [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ntp       [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 fe80::b4:ebff:fe34::ntp [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                             
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7438     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1583287  /srv/www/icon_sae/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5887     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11658    /run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7586     /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     6093     /run/udev/control
```

a HTTP POST request to localhost:8888 in the Ubuntu host gave the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://localhost:8888/api/text/">http://localhost:8888/api/text/</a>.  If not click the link.
```

Comment: "Production" is just a label, so if it's possible on your local machine it's entirely possible somewhere else. What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Hi John, I get your point. I was thinking the same too. However in production, I can't access "localhost:8888" like in development even I already run python server and do ps aux to see python service run in backgroun, when i do HTTP POST request call localhost:8888 it just doesn't work.

Comment: There should be nothing stopping you from doing that, barring misconfiguration of your application or security rules (firewall) that prevent localhost connections on your instance.  If both are correct then your application should be able to connect to ports localhost without restriction - I have run Tomcat, neo4j, Apache and Zope/Plone on the same host without issues connecting to each other.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster thanks for your comment. I have do IPTable to allow service on port 8888. still I can't call "localhost:8888".  May i know on your mentioned deployment, how did you call service on different port?

Comment: Check python server logs - it might have failed to open 8888 port due to misconfiguration/firewall rules/some other application/etc.

Comment: @J0HN good call. I did IPTable open up port 8888. I will double check again. I did ps aux|grep python i see it is running...

Comment: Running != captured 8888 port. If it's configured to continue on fail it will still run, deaf and blind :)

Comment: @metatoaster thanks, I did "netstat --listen" and see 

"tcp        0      0 *:8888                  *:*        LISTEN"

I update it in question. does that mean port 8888 is accessible? with "*:8888" how should i replace base url with in the code?

Comment: @sovanlandy if you can POST directly your python application listening on that port and it returns an HTTP error status it seems to me that the problem lies with the application.  Check your log files and if applicable post the relevant traceback.

Comment: @metatoaster what you said make sense. I did some debugging. A POST request gave me this raw error. I update the question to contain the post Error. As you can see it is having some redirecting problem... any hint on the error you can think of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @metatoaster and J0HN I finally got it working. Thanks alot for you guys inputs. They are helpful :)

Comment: @sovanlandy not explaining how you got it working is downright criminal!